# EntityFramework, TransactionScope and SaveChange

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working on a c# project with **EntityFramework** and the last developer wrote that:

```
using (System.Transactions.TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted }))
{
    try
    {
        //... do somehting
        context.SaveChanges();

        //... do some other work
        context.SaveChanges();

        scope.Complete();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       context.RollbackChanges();
       scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

I don't understand why he is using `TransactionScope`. I tried to throw an exception between the 2 `SaveChanges` and it didnt **rollback** the first call modification.

Why using `TransactionScope`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should explain it for you - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexj/2009/01/11/savechangesfalse/

Edit: as per szer's request.

They key take-away from the link is :

"If you call SaveChanges() or SaveChanges(true),the EF simply assumes that if its work completes okay, everything is okay, so it will discard the changes it has been tracking, and wait for new changes."

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the `Rollback()` method on the scope object. To create the scope, call `context.Database.BeginTransaction()`:

```
using (var scope = context.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
{ 
    try 
    { 
        // do some stuff 
        context.SaveChanges(); 

        // do other stuff 
        context.SaveChanges(); 

        scope.Commit(); 
    } 
    catch (Exception) 
    { 
        scope.Rollback(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why are you using BeginTransaction over a new TransactionScope? and what about the isolationLevel specified?

Answer (score 3):

Like Marc explained you need to roll back the `TransactionScope`, not the EF context transaction. `TransactionScope` creates an ambient transaction that operations can enlist in. So what you're doing here is creating a transaction that wraps multiple transactions and can commit or rollback all of them at once.

What's happening in your code is this:

1. You're committing query 1 (with the SaveChanges call).
2. You're committing query 2 (with the SaveChanges call).
3. Error occurs.
4. You're rolling back the latest transaction (query 2). Note that query 1 is still committed.
5. You're committing the ambient transaction, 'saving' the results. This means that the final result is that query 1 was committed and query 2 was rolled back.